# TBB function_node with member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

Imagine, I have a class MyClass and want to implement multi-threading with Intel TBB:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   tbb::flow::function_node<int, double>* _fnode;
private:
   tbb::flow::graph* _graph;
   double fbody(int inp);
}
```

Is it possible to initialize `_fnode` with class-member function? Simple way does not work:

```
_fnode = new tbb::flow::function_node<int, double>(*_graph,1,MyClass::fbody)
```

Comment: Use bind.
Example from related page:
function_node<int,int>* pSubtracter2 =
    new function_node<int,int>(m_graph, m_concurrency, 
                               bind(&IHelloTool::addToIt, clonedPrivate, _1));
http://atlas-computing.web.cern.ch/atlas-computing/links/buildDirectory/AtlasOffline/19.2.2/InstallArea/doc/TBBExamples/html/classHelloGraphAlg.html

The function MyClass::fbody needs to be called on an instance of MyClass.
You need to bind the instance with the member function.

Comment: Jonathan, thank You, this solution really works! :) If you don't mind, I put in  question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Jonathan for his idea to use std::bind. So, the solution of this problem:

```
_fnode = new tbb::flow::function_node<int, double>(*_graph,1,std::bind(&MyClass::fbody, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```